# Validation for unique username not working in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I trying to validate username for uniqueness but due to some reasons its not working fine. I am doing it in the following way

**MODEL**

```
public class System_User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Remote("doesUserNameExist", "System_User", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "User name already exists. Please enter a different user name.")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

I have added the following code to my System_User Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult doesUserNameExist(string UserName)
        {

            var user = Membership.GetUser(UserName);

            return Json(user == null);
        }
```

**View**
I have the default create view generated by mvc with necessary references to jquery

```
@model WhiteBoard.Models.System_User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


    <table class="userTable">
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsAdmin)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsAdmin)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsAdmin)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td colspan="2">
                <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Create User" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
<div>
    <p>

        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

When I ran the application, it neither threw an exception nor the validation worked.

May I know where am I making a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue is:

```
return Json(user == null);
```

If the user is null, you will return true when you want to return false, the user does not exists.  Change it to

```
return Json(user != null);
```

If that doesn't work or if the == was just a type please let us know in the comments what username you entered, what the expected result was, and what the actual result was.

Comment: If the user!=null then it always returns false and says that user name is already in use. when I use user==null then as you said it always returns true and it takes the username even if its already in use

Comment: If you examine user in a breakpoint what is returned?  Does the user actually exist?  Is this a build in Membership provider or one you wrote yourself?

Comment: thats a built in membership provider and user is always null ans obviously thats the problem.

Comment: Did you set up the membership provider in your web.config?  Are you trying to connect to a database or to active directory?

Comment: Yes I have everything set up in membership provider and I am connecting to a database